# SQL Parameter not filtering appropriate data

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I am passing a parameter `@employeeID` to my SQL Server procedure, which I am using as a filter to my query. It is not filtering the data correctly. I can see that the value is of same type as the filtering column but not getting any results.

Here is the code.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchAssociatesById] 
    @EmployeeID VARCHAR(20)
AS
BEGIN
    PRINT @EmployeeID

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT * 
    FROM ASSOCIATE A
    WHERE empl_id = @EmployeeID
END
```

The result is empty, but the value of `@employeeID` is printed correctly. If I do the same thing by hardcoding my `employeeID`, then I get the correct result.

What am I missing here ?

The data type of `Empl_id` is `varchar(11)`

[image: This is when i use variable <code>@EmployeeID</code>]

Comment: Can you give us some sample data so that we can reproduce the issue?

Comment: The code posted should work. That means there is something else going on here. I would suggest using the same datatype as the column but that shouldn't prevent this from working. What values work when you hard code them and what is the code you are running to call your procedure?

Comment: Possible you have embedded spaces in the parameter? Sample data and expected results would help.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.

Comment: To rule out something obvious, try: where empl_id = rtrim(ltrim(@EmployeeID))

Comment: @SeanLange It runs when I specifically give a value '00000137464' in the filter condition, and run the procedure with that condition. I am guessing something to do with how the parameter is evaluated, but I cant seem to find what is missing.

Comment: @WEI_DBA Attached screenshots

Comment: Can you validate that the EmployeeID exists in the data, please? I'm not doubting you, something just isn't right here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you provided is working well.

Maybe the issue is in the data itself.

try to alter your procedure as next:-

```
Alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchAssociatesById] 
@EmployeeID varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN
print @EmployeeID

SET NOCOUNT ON;
select * 
FROM ASSOCIATE A
 where rtrim(ltrim(empl_id)) = @EmployeeID
end
```

**Demo:-**

```
Create table ASSOCIATE (empl_id varchar(11),name varchar(200))
insert into ASSOCIATE values ('   1','aaaaaaaaaaaa')
```

while using your code without using `LTRIM` & `RTRIM` funtions

```
exec [SearchAssociatesById] '2'
```

**Result:-**

[image]

and with using `LTRIM` & `RTRIM` funtions

```
exec [SearchAssociatesById] '2'
```

**Result:-**

[image]